# React native iOS - Cannot receive any notifications before the app opens second time or first time launching app not receiving notification

Tags: firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase, react-native-push-notification

```
used library versions
```

==================
"@react-native-firebase/app": "8.4.6",
"@react-native-firebase/messaging": "8.0.0",
"react": "16.8.3",
"react-native": "0.63.3",

Answer (score 0):

IOS with latest React Native and it seemed to persist even after uploading a production build to TestFlight. Downgrading the libraries solved the issue for me:

"@react-native-firebase/app": "^8.4.6" => "@react-native-firebase/app": "~8.2.0",
"@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^8.0.0" => "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "~7.5.0"
On iOS notifications were only received on second app launch and after, Android had no issues at all